# How do I receive refresh_token with google Oauth in angular js while integrating Google Plus

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, google-plus

My code looks like this. It doesnot return me the refresh token

```
  gapi.signin.render('signInButton',
  {
    'callback': $scope.signInCallback,
    'clientid': '***', 
    'requestvisibleactions': 'http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity',
    'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
    'cookiepolicy': 'single_host_origin',
    'access_type': 'offline'
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

For security reasons `refresh_token` is not available in `implicit grant type` of OAuth 2.0. So you can not get `refresh_token` with javascript

Comment: How do I get the refresh_token then. The access_token seems to expire in an hour. Any idea how to implement this?

Comment: @SurajAcharya If you want to use refresh_token you have to create a  `server-side` application using PHP, Java or .Net ... In this case only with javascript you can set `'approval_prompt':'force'`user will auto login at next time click on login button.